# Original data vs reference data?

Tags: publications, data, databases

A journal asks to upload/link the data and code used in your article. I have a Github repository with data and code. One of the questions in the form is:

> Are you linking to original data reported in your research, or are you linking to reference data which is supporting your article?

and you have to select either `Original` or `Reference`. This is rather confusing to me. What would constitute "original data"? If I downloaded some data and processed, arranged, and/or classified it, is is still "original"? Furthermore, all data used "supports my article".

Could someone explain the difference between the two, preferably with examples?

Comment: Your guess is as good as ours. Ask the journal.

Comment: Louic is correct, ask the journal. I am only guessing. But my guess is, original data is data you produced. By measuring, collecting (such as surveys), or calculating it yourself. Reference data is data that comes from somebody else and that you are just citing.